# Have Raspberry Pi and Server occasionally ping each other to check status

Tags: raspberry-pi, webserver, x-server, file-server

Is there a way to have my Raspberry pi and my Server occasionally ping each other to check that they're still online, and if not, then email me to tell me?

For example if my Pi pings the server every hour, and same with the server pining the pi. If there is no response from one of them, then I get an email telling me?

I'm sure I could set up a cron job to ping the server, but I'm not sure how to use the information received and to email myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Putting a script like the one below in `/etc/cron.hourly`should be able to accomplish your goal. The `$?` grabs the exit status and if it not equal to 0 then it executes the command, otherwise it does nothing.

```
#!/bin/bash
email=user@localhost
address=192.168.0.2

ping -c 3 "${address}" > /dev/null 2>&1
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Pi is down" | mailx -s "Pi is down" "${email}"
  fi
```